# printing int with specified nr of digits

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nslog

I am trying to print out a 5 digit number as follows:

```
int rdmNr = arc4random()%100000;
NSLog(@"%i",rdmNr);
```

I always would like to have 5 digit numbers. Example outputs should be:

```
00001
10544
00555
78801
```

But with the previous code I would also get 1 or 555 without 0s. I also tried %5i, but the I just get more white spaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try

```
NSLog(@"%05i",rdmNr);
```

In general, you can specify 2 types of padding for NSLog - filling the required extra characters with spaces (`@"%5i"`) or with leading zeros (`@"%05i"`)

Answer (score 6):

```
NSLog(@"%05i", rdmNr);
```

The `5` means that 5 characters should be printed, the `0` means that it should be padded with zeros to the left.

NSLog accepts the same arguments as `printf` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)) in addition `%@` prints an NSString, more info [here](http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog).

Answer (score 0):

You can also find some common specifiers at [Placeholders on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#printf_format_placeholders)